# Showing $(a^{2}+2)(b^{2}+2)(c^{2}+2)\geq 9(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be nonnegative real numbers.
>   Prove $(a^{2}+2)(b^{2}+2)(c^{2}+2)\geq 9(ab+bc+ca)$.

Comment: I've come up with no idea, which is the purpose of this post.

Comment: you should have mentioned that in the post, which is "the way to ask" question in this site....

Comment: I'd first note that equality is possible with $a=b=c=1$. Not sure if there are any other cases where equality occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will prove the stronger inequality:
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2$$
 because
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)=(a^2+1)(b^2+1)+a^2+b^2+3\ge (a+b)^2+\dfrac{1}{2}(a+b)^2+3
=\dfrac{3}{2}[(a+b)^2+2]$$
so
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge \dfrac{3}{2}[(a+b)^2+2](c^2+2)\ge\dfrac{3}{2}
[\sqrt{2}(a+b)+\sqrt{2}c]^2=3(a+b+c)^2$$
so
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2\ge 9(ab+bc+ac)$$

Comment: very nice +1 and holds for all reals.  Sharper still is: $$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2) \ge 9(ab+bc+ca) +\left(abc-\frac{a+b+c}3 \right)^2$$ for which I have a proof only by uvw.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding, we have
$$
\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)=2(a+b)^2+(ab-2)^2\tag1
$$
Substituting $b\mapsto b+c$, we get
$$
\left(a^2+2\right)\left((b+c)^2+2\right)=2(a+b+c)^2+(a(b+c)-2)^2\tag2
$$
Substituting $(a,b)\mapsto(b,c)$ in $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right)
&=2(b+c)^2+(bc-2)^2\\
&=(b+c)^2+(b-c)^2+4bc+(bc-2)^2\tag{3a}\\
&=(b+c)^2+(b-c)^2+b^2c^2+4\tag{3b}\\
&=(b+c)^2+b^2+c^2-2bc+b^2c^2+4\tag{3c}\\
&=(b+c)^2+2+b^2+c^2+(bc-1)^2+1\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: $(b+c)^2=(b-c)^2+4bc$
$\text{(3b)}$: $4bc+(bc-2)^2=b^2c^2+4$
$\text{(3c)}$: $(b-c)^2=b^2+c^2-2bc$
$\text{(3d)}$: $b^2c^2-2bc+1=(bc-1)^2$

Multiply $(3)$ by $a^2+2$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right)\\
&=\left(a^2+2\right)\left((b+c)^2+2\right)+\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+c^2+(bc-1)^2+1\right)\\
&=2(a+b+c)^2\color{#AAA}{+(a(b+c)-2)^2}+\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+c^2\color{#AAA}{+(bc-1)^2}+1\right)\tag{4a}\\
&=2(a+b+c)^2+\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+c^2+1\right)\\
&\:\color{#AAA}{+\left(a^2+2\right)(bc-1)^2+(a(b+c)-2)^2}\tag{4b}\\
&=2(a+b+c)^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+1+a^2c^2+1\\
&\:\color{#AAA}{+\left(a^2+2\right)(bc-1)^2+(a(b+c)-2)^2}\tag{4c}\\
&=2(a+b+c)^2+a^2+b^2+c^2\\
&+2bc\color{#AAA}{+(b-c)^2}+2ab\color{#AAA}{+(ab-1)^2}+2ac\color{#AAA}{+(ac-1)^2}\\
&\:\color{#AAA}{+\left(a^2+2\right)(bc-1)^2+(a(b+c)-2)^2}\tag{4d}\\
&=3(a+b+c)^2\\
&\:\color{#AAA}{+\,(b-c)^2+(ab-1)^2+(ac-1)^2+\left(a^2+2\right)(bc-1)^2+(a(b+c)-2)^2}\tag{4e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(4b)}$: rearrange terms
$\text{(4c)}$: expand product
$\text{(4d)}$: complete squares
$\text{(4e)}$: $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca$

Thus,
$$
\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right)\ge3(a+b+c)^2\tag5
$$
and equality only happens when $a=b=c=\pm1$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right)\\
&\ge3(a+b+c)^2\tag{6a}\\
&=6(ab+bc+ca)+3\!\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\tag{6b}\\
&=6(ab+bc+ca)\\
&\:+3\!\left(ab\color{#AAA}{+\tfrac12(a-b)^2}+bc\color{#AAA}{+\tfrac12(b-c)^2}+ca\color{#AAA}{+\tfrac12(c-a)^2}\right)\tag{6c}\\
&=9(ab+bc+ca)\color{#AAA}{+\tfrac32\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)}\tag{6d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a)}$: $(5)$
$\text{(6b)}$: expand square
$\text{(6c)}$: complete squares
$\text{(6d)}$: collect terms

Thus,
$$
\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right)\ge9(ab+bc+ca)\tag7
$$
where equality happens only when $a=b=c=\pm1$.

Note that if equality happens in $(5)$, then equality happens in $(7)$ (the converse is obvious).