# Inequality and Trigonometric Substitution

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that for all positive real $a,b,c$, we have 
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2) \geq 9(ab+bc+ca).$$

Because of the term $a^2+2$, this motiveates me to substitute $a=\sqrt{2}\tan A, b=\sqrt{2}\tan B, c=\sqrt{2}\tan C$ and the fact that $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$, then the desired inequality becomes
$$2^2\sec^2 A\sec^2 B \sec^2 C\geq 3^2(\tan A\tan C + \tan B\tan C + \tan C \tan A).$$

But then I was stuck and couldn't move further, please helps.

Comment: A nice question !

Comment: Of course it's true for all reals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,if you use  trigonometry to solve it

as you 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}(\cos{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}+\sin{A}\cos{B}\sin{C}+\sin{A}\sin{B}\cos{C})\le\dfrac{4}{9}$$
$$\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}(\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}-\cos{(A+B+C)})\le\dfrac{4}{9}$$
By Jenson inequality we have
$$\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}\le\cos^3{\dfrac{A+B+C}{3}}$$
so let $$\cos{\dfrac{A+B+C}{3}}=x,\Longrightarrow \cos{(A+B+C)}=4x^3-3x$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x^4(1-x^2)\le \dfrac{4}{27},0<x<1$$
Use AM-GM inequality we have
$$x^4(1-x^2)=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2\cdot x^2\cdot (2-2x^2)\le\dfrac{4}{27}$$

PS:you can prove this stronger $$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2\ge 9(ab+bc+ac)$$

see [Showing $~\prod (a^{2}+2)\geq 9\sum ab$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834025/showing-prod-a22-geq-9-sum-ab/834053#834053)